# Beppo-Levi: Reverse

Tags: integration, measure-theory, alternative-proof

For a merely decreasing positive sequence it fails:
$$f_n:=\frac{1}{n}\chi_{[n,\infty)}:\quad\int f_n\mathrm{d}\lambda=\infty\nrightarrow0$$

For a dominated decreasing positive sequence it holds:
$$0\leq f_n\downarrow f:\quad\int f_n\mathrm{d}\mu\to \int f\mathrm{d}\mu\quad(f_n\in\mathcal{L})$$
How to prove this via Beppo-Levi?

Comment: What are you trying to prove? Use words, please.

Comment: I'm trying to prove Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem for positive functions?

Comment: Can't you just use that $f = (f -s_n) + s_n$, so that $\int f = \int (f -s_n) + \int s_n$. Now use that $\int s_n \to \int f$ and note that you can substract $\int f$ from both sides, because it is finite.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Or what did you mean?

Comment: @PhoemueX: Perfect thats precisely what I needed =D thanks alot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since my comment seems to answer the question, let me repeat the argument as an answer...*

Denote for shorthand: $\bar{f}:=\sup_n f_n$

By measurability for positive functions one has:

$$\int f_n \mathrm{d}\mu = \int \bar{f} \mathrm{d}\mu + \int (\bar{f}-f_n) \mathrm{d}\mu$$
$$\int f \mathrm{d}\mu = \int \bar{f} \mathrm{d}\mu + \int (\bar{f}-f) \mathrm{d}\mu$$

By monotone convergence one has:

$$\int(\bar{f}-f_n)\mathrm{d}\mu\to\int(\bar{f}-f)\mathrm{d}\mu$$

It remains to observe that all integrals are finite to conclude:
$$\int f_n\mathrm{d}\mu=\int\bar{f}\mathrm{d}\mu-\int(\bar{f}-f_n)\mathrm{d}\mu\to\int\bar{f}\mathrm{d}\mu-\int(\bar{f}-f)\mathrm{d}\mu=\int f\mathrm{d}\mu$$

Comment: @PhoemuX: Do you mind if I adjust your answer? *(I slightly modified the problem to the key setting of your answer.)*

Comment: As always, feel free to edit :)

Comment: @PhoemuX: Thanks. :D